# How does isoweek.Week manage to be json - encodeable (python2)

Tags: python, json

If I instantiate a 'Week' from the [isoweek - package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isoweek/1.0.1), like this:

```
from isoweek import Week
week = Week(2015,24)
```

Then `week` is a json - serializable:

```
>>>json.dumps(week)
>>>'[2015, 25]'
```

How does the week-class pull this off?

<s>(isoweek.Week inherits from namedtuple, which is not json-serializable.)</s>

---

EDIT: so apparently namedtuple *is* json-serializable, but that leaves me with the question: How does it do this?

Comment: I tried it myself, and made a mistake initializing the namedtuple. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> inherits from namedtuple, which is not json-serializable

I think this is wrong, see:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import json

week = namedtuple("week", ['year', 'week'])
w = week(2015, 15)
print json.dumps(w)

[2015, 15]
```

instances of classes generated from the `namedtuple` factory are derived from `tuple`, and because of that are [JSON serializable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder):

```
isinstance(w, tuple)
True
```

Comment: So `namedtuple` is a class factory, not a class in fact? But `week` in your example is already an instance of a class, or am I confused here?

Comment: It's worth looking at the source in collections.py. There's a lot of validation & processing first, but the guts of the `namedtuple()` involves a template string that's formatted with the particulars of your new type that is `exec`ed in a namespace, creating a new subclass of tuple on the fly (that's returned as the return value of the `namedtuple()` function. In this instance, `week` is a new class created by the `namedtuple()` fn.